# Is there a way to change the color of PShape without entering begin/end?

Tags: processing

I've been writing a program which redraws lots of (several hundred) the same PShape in different colors. However, I haven't found a way to redraw the PShape in different colors without actually recreating the PShape, i.e. going through the begin/end shape redoing all the vertices and simply changing the fill and then assigning it to a new PShape variable. I've tried things like tint(), fill(), setFill() and they all seem to require being called in begin/end shape.

**Is there a way to redraw a PShape in different colors without redefining the shape completely and assigning it to a new variable?**

Any help greatly appreciated.

(Here is a sort of collation of the different things I tried)

```
   PShape p;

    void setup()
{
  size(600,600,P2D);
  p = createShape();
  p.beginShape();
  p.vertex(0, 0);
  p.vertex(20, 0);
  p.vertex(20, 20);
  p.vertex(0, 20);
  p.endShape(CLOSE);
}

void draw()
{
  p.tint(200,100,30);
  p.fill(200,100,30);
  p.setFill(0,0);
  shape(p,100,100);
}
```

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: No, `begin` and `end` enter and leave context, if you aren't in the context you can't change anything in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use PShape's [disableStyle()](http://processing.org/reference/PShape_disableStyle_.html) to disable it's rendering style and use Processing's (your sketches'):

```
PShape p;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600, P2D);
  p = createShape();
  p.beginShape();
  p.vertex(0, 0);
  p.vertex(20, 0);
  p.vertex(20, 20);
  p.vertex(0, 20);
  p.endShape(CLOSE);
  //disable the PShape's default styles and use Processing's 
  p.disableStyle();
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++){
      fill(i/30.0*255, 100, 30);
      shape(p, i * 20,300);
  }
}
```

For such a simple shape you can of course use [rect()](http://processing.org/reference/rect_.html), but I assume that's a place holder for something more complex. Other things to explore are [beginShape()](http://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html) and maybe [createGraphics()](http://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! (Yes it's a placeholder)