# Processing, unable to set alpha value for objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, processing, alpha

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218251/processing-ellipse-not-following-alpha-values/39227721#39227721).

I am looking to get a bunch of particle objects to stay at a certain 'alpha' value. This alpha value will increase/decrease based on its proximity with neighboring particles.

Currently the code I have results in all particles staying at max alpha. I believe this is due to the iterating through the ArrayList results in the alpha being redrawn multiple times. The program runs sluggishly due to this too.

```
  class Particle{

  PVector velocity, location; //PVector variables for each particle.

  Particle(){ //Constructor - random location and speed for each particle.
    velocity = new PVector(random(-0.5,0.5), random(-0.5,0.5));
    location = new PVector(random(0,width),random(0,width));
  }

  void update() { location.add(velocity); } //Motion method.

  void edge() {  //Wraparound case for particles.
    if (location.x > width) {location.x = 0;} 
    else if (location.x < 0) {location.x = width;}

    if (location.y > height) {location.y = 0;}
    else if (location.y < 0) {location.y = height;}
  }

  void display(ArrayList<Particle> p){ //Display method to show lines and ellipses between particles.

    for(Particle other: p){ //For every particle in the ArrayList.
     float d = PVector.dist(location,other.location); //Get distance between any two particle.
     float a = 255 - map(d,0,112,0,255); //Map variable 'a' as alpha based on distance. E.g. if distance is high, d = 100, alpha is low, a = 255 - 225 = 30.

if(other==this){continue;}

     println("Lowest distance of any two particle =" + d); //Debug output.

     if(d<112){ //If the distance of any two particle falls bellow 112.
      noStroke(); //No outline.
      fill(0,a); //Particle are coloured black, 'a' to vary alpha.
      ellipse(location.x, location.y, 8, 8); //Draw ellipse based on location of particle.

    }else{
      noStroke(); //No outline.
      fill(0,30); //For particles far away, set them to a fix alpha of '30'
      ellipse(location.x, location.y, 8, 8); //Draw ellipse based on location of particle.
    }
  }
}
}

ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>(); //Create a new arraylist of type Particle.

void setup(){
  size(640,640,P2D); //Setup frame of sketch.

    for (int i=0; i<40; i++) { 
  particles.add(new Particle()); //Add five Particle elements into arraylist.
    }
}

void draw(){
 background(255); //Set white background.
 for(Particle p: particles){ //For every 'p' of type Particle in arraylist particles.
   p.update(); //Update location based on velocity.
   p.display(particles); //Display each particle in relation to other particles.
   p.edge(); //Wraparound if particle reaches edge of screen.
 }
}
```

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18015/processing-ellipse-not-following-alpha-values#latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same problem from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218251/processing-ellipse-not-following-alpha-values/39227721#39227721): for each `Particle`, you're looping through **every** other `Particle`, so you end up drawing 40 ellipses for every single `Particle`. Instead, you need to loop through the `Particle`s and locate the closest neighbor, then base your alpha calculations off that **one** `Particle`.

In other words, your drawing code should happen **after** the `for` loop.

Locating the closest neighbor looks like this:

```
Particle closestNeighbor = null;
float closestDistance = 100000;

for (Particle other : p) { //For every particle in the ArrayList.

  if (other == this) {
    continue;
  }


  float d = PVector.dist(location, other.location);
  if (d < closestDistance) {
    closestDistance = d;
    closestNeighbor = other;
  }
}
```

After this loop completes, `closestNeighbor` will point to the closest neighbor, and `closestDistance` will be the closest distance. You can use this in your calculations of alpha:

```
float a = 255 - map(closestDistance, 0, 112, 0, 255); //Map variable 'a' as alpha based on distance. E.g. if distance is high, d = 100, alpha is low, a = 255 - 225 = 30.

if (closestDistance<112) {
  noStroke(); //No outline.
  fill(0, a); //Particle are coloured black, 'a' to vary alpha.
  ellipse(location.x, location.y, 8, 8); //Draw ellipse based on location of particle.
} else {
  noStroke(); //No outline.
  fill(0, 30); //For particles far away, set them to a fix alpha of '30'
  ellipse(location.x, location.y, 8, 8); //Draw ellipse based on location of particle.
}
```